# Guardar e imprimir una matriz de otro archivo usando una función

Tags: c, matrices

Este programa debería llamar a una función la cual abrirá un archivo externo y lo recorrerá contando sus líneas, después crea un puntero doble  una matriz y lo vuelve a recorrer pero ahora guardando sus datos en la matriz y regresa como resultado de la función esa misma matriz, después de esto el programa principal imprime la matriz.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int tam;
float **carga_archivo(char *nombre_archivo);
int main()
{
    int i,j;
    char *nombre_archivo="Agua_Vapor.txt";
    float **agua_vapor=carga_archivo(nombre_archivo);
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; i < tam; i++)
            printf("%f   ", agua_vapor[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
float **carga_archivo(char *nombre_archivo)
{
    int i=0;
    float P[300][6];
    FILE *archivo;
    archivo=fopen(nombre_archivo,"r");
    while(!feof(archivo))
    {
        i++;
        fscanf(archivo,"%f\t%f\t%f\t%f\t%f\t%f\n",
                  &P[0][i],&P[1][i],&P[2][i],&P[3][i],&P[4][i],&P[5][i]);
        //Esta parte es solo para que el programa pueda contar renglón por renglón
        //De otro modo contaría carácter por carácter, Realmente no hace nada
        //(No conozco el comando o condición para que cuente de esa forma)
    }
    tam=i;
    printf("%i",tam);
    int filas = 6;
    int columnas = tam;
    float **M = (float **)malloc(filas*sizeof(float*));
    for (i=0;i<filas;i++)
        M[i] = (float*)malloc(columnas*sizeof(float));
    for (i = 0; i < columnas; ++i)
        fscanf(archivo,"%f\t%f\t%f\t%f\t%f\t%f\n",&M[0][i],&M[1][i],
                                       &M[2][i],&M[3][i],&M[4][i],&M[5][i]);
    fclose (archivo);
    return M;
}
```

El problema es que cuando la matriz debería ser impresa el programa se interrumpe y sale, sé que el programa realmente guarda los datos debido a que si los imprimo en la misma función si se imprimen, así que creo que el problema puede estar ya sea en la forma de declarar la matriz como doble puntero, la forma que se declara la función o la forma en la que se llama a la función.
Pd. El archivo que se abre es un conjunto de datos ordenados separados por tabulaciones (una tabla de 6 columnas) como lo que se muestra en a continuación:

> 0.06  36.16   23.739  2425.0  2567.4  8.3304
>
> 0.06  80.00   27.132  2487.3  2650.1  8.5804
>
> 0.06  120.00  30.219  2544.7  2726.0  8.7840
>
> 0.06  160.00  33.302  2602.7  2802.5  8.9693
>
> 0.06  200.00  36.383  2661.4  2879.7  9.1398
>
> 0.06  240.00  39.462  2721.0  2957.8  9.2982
>
> 0.06  280.00  42.540  2781.5  3036.8  9.4464
>
> 0.06  320.00  45.618  2843.0  3116.7  9.5859
>
> 0.06  360.00  48.696  2905.5  3197.7  9.7180
>
> 0.06  400.00  51.774  2969.0  3279.6  9.8435

(no se pueden distinguir las tabulaciones pero están ahí)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
float P[300][6];
while(!feof(archivo))
{
    fscanf(archivo,"%f\t%f\t%f\t%f\t%f\t%f\n",
              &P[0][i],&P[1][i],&P[2][i],&P[3][i],&P[4][i],&P[5][i]);
}
```

Fíjate que en la variable `P` la dimensión *6* se encuentra en el segundo nivel, mientras que en el bucle estás asumiendo que se encuentra en el primer nivel.

Estás intercambiando los índices en el bucle. Lo correcto sería esto:

```
float P[300][6];
while(!feof(archivo))
{
    fscanf(archivo,"%f\t%f\t%f\t%f\t%f\t%f\n",
              &P[i][0],&P[i][1],&P[i][2],&P[i][3],&P[i][4],&P[i][5]);
}
```

Por otro lado:

```
while(!feof(archivo))
{
  // ...
} // (1)

// ...

for (i = 0; i < columnas; ++i)
    fscanf(archivo,"%f\t%f\t%f\t%f\t%f\t%f\n",&M[0][i],&M[1][i],
                                   &M[2][i],&M[3][i],&M[4][i],&M[5][i]); // (2)
fclose (archivo);
```

1. En este punto el puntero del fichero se encuentra al final del mismo.
2. Ahora intentas rellenar la matriz... pero el puntero sigue al final del fichero

La consecuencia es que no vas a leer nada.

Una posibilidad es, ya que has leído el fichero, copiar el contenido de `P` a `M`:

```
for (i = 0; i < columnas; ++i)
{
  M[0][i] = P[0][i];
  // ...
}
```

Otra posibilidad pasa por resetear el puntero del fichero, de forma que vuelva al inicio del mismo:

```
fseek(archivo,0,SEEK_SET);

float **M = (float **)malloc(filas*sizeof(float*));
for (i=0;i<filas;i++)
    M[i] = (float*)malloc(columnas*sizeof(float));
for (i = 0; i < columnas; ++i)
    fscanf(archivo,"%f\t%f\t%f\t%f\t%f\t%f\n",&M[0][i],&M[1][i],
                                   &M[2][i],&M[3][i],&M[4][i],&M[5][i]);
```

Por cierto, para saber cuántas líneas tiene un fichero puedes hacer esto:

```
while(!feof(archivo))
{
  ch = fgetc(archivo);
  if(ch == '\n')
  {
    i++;
  }
}
```

Lo cual es más rápido y legible que leer dos veces el array.